# install SIP/PyQt4/Ghost on windows 7 and Python 2.7.9

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, ghost.py

after searching for an answer and since i'm new to python and not knowledgeable enough, i really need help with this.

it starts from my need to use ghost.py. for this installation i need PyQt and before that i need SIP installed. so when downloading [SIP](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download) i tried following the instructions and got to a point where, after running python configure.py ,i need to run "make" and then "make install". my question is  - where can i get teh software to run "make" ? i tried GNU make - can this work ? because it seem to fail , giving me gibberish....

installing PyQt also requires this so it will help me twice :)

thanks in advance
Sivan

Comment: If you just want to install PyQt, then there is a binary package on riverbank, no need to install SIP

Comment: thanks , i downloaded it ,installed PyQt4 ,then cloned ghost  but for some reason when trying to import ghost ,it didnt recognize that i have PyQt4. so i just installed PySide and it worked. i cant say if what i did is ok but for now ghost seems to be working so... thank you for your quick answer.